# Image index corresponds to matrix index

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, indexing

I want to display a corresponding image index within a folder, to a corresponding number that is in a matrix.

for example

```
 J = imread('image2.jpg');           
 axes(handles.axes1);          
 imshow(J);
```

but somehow have the J = imread('image 'x'.jpg') and x will have to be changing as values from the matrix change.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, are you looking for something like [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)? E.g. `filename = sprintf('image%d.jpg', index);`

Comment: yes this was the answer i was looking for, thank you.